# wcf data services to know if query is started by application code or through browser address bar

Tags: wcf-data-services

WE created WCF data services. is there any way by which we can check that is this request comes from my application code or some one just type the service address in toolbar.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think there's any way to distinguish the two - unless you explicitly send some HTTP header from your application which would be missing if someone types in the request URL in the browser....

Answer (score 0):

Other than HTTP headers there's nothing you can rely on. Most browsers send the User-Agent header set to well known values. This is what web servers use to serve browser dependent HTML. You can use the same trick.
Your application can send some other header or use the User-Agent.

Comment: Using headers will work, but use is clever then he/she can see my request and change the header accordingly.

Comment: If you want this to be a security feature (nobody else can do something with your service but the app), then getting that right is super hard. You would need some kind of secret in the app which only the app knows. But since the app code resides on the client anybody can go read the secret. For security the best approach seems to be to treat all incoming requests the same and guard against malicious stuff on the server. Basically - never trust the client, even if it is your own app.